# Multiple Domains to One Dynamic Site

Tags: .htaccess, dynamic, url-rewriting, dns, url-routing

I am building a website for a company who has multiple users/sale people and each user needs their own website.  What I want to accomplish is building one site that pulls in each users information dynamically.  So i will build one site and pull in each users info dynamically.  For example:

```
www.company.com/Mike
www.company.com/Steve
www.company.com/Jason
```

Each url would then pull in that particular user's information and content using sessions, cookies and url variables. This would then make each url look like a different site although it is the same site with dynamic data.  I know how to accomplish this but what i would really like to accomplish is giving each user their own domain.

My question is:  How do I allow each user to set up a unique domain and then point that domain to the url that dynamically pulls in the dynamic data:

```
Mike.com --> www.company.com/Mike 
Steve.com --> www.company.com/Steve
Jason.com --> www.company.com/Jason
```

I want to accomplish this and make sure that their site is SEO friendly like a stand alone site. I know that i could just forward the url but i would like something that acts more like an actual site and is SEO friendly.

I am building this in php, mysql and javascript.  I am running the site on LAMP server set up.  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using apache, you can use mod_rewrite to do the rewriting. Try adding this to your .htaccess file:

```
# Match the host
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.com$ [NC]

# proxy the entire request to the /host/ and path
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.company.com/%1/$1  [L,P]
```

This will make it so requesting http://Mike.com/page.html will serve http://www.company.com/Mike/page.html

Comment: I make this change in the htaccess file on the mike.com root folder/host or on the www.company.com root forlder/host?

Comment: Do you know if for seo this will effect duplicate content?  Also do you know if the links coming into the new site will give the mike.come site the juice or the company.com site?  Thanks.

Comment: Links incoming to mike.com will get juice for mike.com links, eventhough it is being served content from company.com.