# Static files are nor serving while Proxy the request in mod_rewrite Apache

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, url-rewrite-module, static-files, dynamic-routing

I am having a website that serves data based on url. Example:

```
example.com/data1
example.com/data2
```

What I want is to give customers to serve their data on their custom domain. example

```
user1.com --> example.com/user1
```

i.e when we visit user1.com, it will proxy the request example.com/user1 behind the scene.
For this, I am using apache2 mod_rewrite with below rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.in$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1 [L,P]
```

The problem is, the website on example.com is a react build website, so when I am proxying the request to example.com, the static files gives me 404 error. How do I add Rewrite rules to serve static files on example.com? Or is there any method to do this?
Reference question: [Multiple Domains to One Dynamic Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289282/multiple-domains-to-one-dynamic-site)

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please do let us know if you have any other rules other than shown ones in your htaccess rules file? If no then from which files data1 is being served with?

Comment: example.com/data1 is a static website serving through cloudfront. I want to proxy request from user1.com to example.com/user1. I hope this answers what you were asking @RavinderSingh13